# Similar directives not behaving similarly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Both of these directives are in the same module. 
First directive:

```
.directive('welcomeAndLog', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: "<div ng-show=\"currentUser.get('username')\">Welcome {{welcome}}  <span ng-click=\"logOut(user)\">Logout</span> <br /></div>" +
                "<div ng-show=\"!currentUser.get('username')\"><span ng-click=\"fbLogIn()\"> FB LOGIN</span></div>"

        };
    })
```

This one works fine: fbLogIn() correctly triggers the log in process.
This other directive, still in same module:

```
.directive("unloggedWarning", function (mainListFactory) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            template: '<div ng-show="notLogged == 1">You are not logged in</div>' +
                '<div id="unLogged" ng-show="notLogged == 2">Not logged in and no data. <span ng-click=\"fbLogIn()\"> FB LOGIN</span></div>',
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.$watch('currentUser', function() {
                    if(scope.currentUser === null && mainListFactory.cachedData) {
                        scope.notLogged = 1;
                    } else if (scope.currentUser === null && !mainListFactory.cachedData) {
                        scope.notLogged = 2;
                    } else
                        scope.notLogged = false;
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

In that second directive, a click that should trigger fbLogIn() causes nothing to happen. It seems totally ignored.
Why in the first, similar case, I can trigger fbLogIn() from the span click, but not in second case ?

Comment: We need to see your markup. Most likely, `fbLogin()` isn't defined on the scope in the second directive.

Comment: That was it, if you want to answer, i'll add explanation and make flag your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is the problem.

The second directive does not have `fbLogin()` on the scope. If you pass this function into the directive, or change the directive scope, it will work.

Comment: Indeed, it was again a scope problem. Solution is simple, but for some reason, I always try to look for the most complex solutions. The second directive was floating outside the scope of fbLogIn, so it produced nothing.